# Lighting a portal in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son is trying to light his portal and I am trying to desperately help him. Every time we use flint and steel, fire appears in the portal instead of the purple light. Help!!!

Comment: Can you please post an image of the portal so we can verify size dimensions? Right now, it sounds like the portal frame is simply the wrong size or too small to turn into a portal to the nether.

Comment: Also, is he definitely using Obsidian? If he's using another material it won't work

Answer (score 6):

As of [Version 0.12.0 Alpha](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_Alpha_0.12.0) release on July 29th, 2015 [Tyler Dood's Answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/202724/30879) is correct.

Before this however the reason why you can't get the portal to work is because in Pocket Edition [The Nether](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether#Pocket_Edition) does not exist as such you can not create a portal to it.

> There is no Nether in Pocket Edition. There is, however, a structure known as the Nether Reactor. It is built from 14 blocks of cobblestone, 4 blocks of gold and 1 nether reactor core.

As per the quote above to access the equivalent in Pocket Edition you need a [Nether Rector](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Nether_Reactor),

> The **nether reactor** is a built structure which, when activated, generates a massive structure of netherrack (35×17×17) with multiple floors called a "nether spire" (unofficial name). It also turns the reactor itself, excluding the core, into glowing obsidian. At this point the reactor will begin to spawn various blocks and items, as well as zombie pigmen (if difficulty is up)

As for the Nether Rector post 0.12.0 Alpha, under [Changes -> Block and Items](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Pocket_Edition_Alpha_0.12.0#Blocks_and_items)

> Still usable, but is uncraftable and removed from the crafting menu. If the player breaks a Nether reactor core, it still drops 3 diamonds and 6 iron ingots.

While all other items normally generated by the reactor can be found normally in The Nether

Comment: Update: [Nether Portals (and the Nether itself) are coming to Minecraft: Pocket Edition in 0.12.0!](http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Pocket_Edition_Alpha_0.12.0)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the portal looks like this:

[image]

The dimensions are 4x5, or you can even exclude the corners. If it still doesn't work, try breaking one block and placing it again. The frame can be built up to 23x23 blocks, but *must* be no smaller, and in the correct "upright" frame (4x5).

Hope this helps!

Comment: Additionally, I have found sometimes that extra blocks behind/in front of the open portal can conflict with the lighting. Make sure the frame is free-standing before lighting :)

Comment: Yeah make sure the portal has at least a couple of blocks of space in front and behind, I tend to give it 2 blocks of clearance in any direction apart from down

Answer (score -1):

The portal is 4×5 obsidian. When ignited by flint and steel, the purple portal apears. If you have minecraft pocket edition 0.12.0, then for the portal to work it must be an infinite world. When you make your new world you can press a button in the corner. It says "advanced". This is where you can chose if you want your world "flat" "infinite" or "old". Chose infinite and your portal should work if its built correctly.

Comment: The question already stated that they're using flint and steel to light it.

Comment: Good to mention flat world still uses old settings so no nether even in most recent version of game.  It must be infinite world as well and if it was upgraded to infinite world it may not work either.

Answer (score -1):

You have to go back to title click on play look at the world you want the portal on. Click on the small pencil next to it click on make infinite, and finally click on make always day. 
This should work and I hope it helps!